# Reading data from hdf5 file, the cost of time increase fast

Tags: python, database, numpy, pandas, hdf5

I have a dataset of the size 1.27gb. Although I can fit it all into memory, it will take a lot of time to do data analysis. My idea is to randomly sample part of the data for analysing.

The language I use is python. I firstly put all the data into the form of hdf5:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

store = pd.HDFStore('train.h5', mode='w')
data_reader = pd.read_csv('./train.csv', chunksize=1e8) 

for i, chuck in enumerate(data_reader):

    store.append('all_train', chuck)

store.close()
```

It did not take a long time to do this, and the produced file is of size 1.64gb:

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: train.h5
/all_train            frame_table     (typ->appendable,nrows->29118021,ncols->6,indexers->[index])
```

Then I try to randomly sample some data through index:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('train.h5')
nrows = store.get_storer('all_train').nrows

r = np.random.randint(0,nrows,size=20)

now = time.time()
print_type(pd.read_hdf('train.h5', 'all_train', where="index=r"))
print 'Time Cost : %f' % (time.time() - now)
```

When the sample size is very small, say 20, it takes 0.2s to sample the data. However, when I increase the size to 35, it takes more than 2min. So why the time cost increase so fast?

And any advice for sampling from large data?

Comment: Did it take 2 mins for just 35 rows? Or 35k rows?